# Endless ListView behaving like a simple ListView

Tags: java, android, eclipse, commonsware-cwac

I am using following code for my ListView..

My `FragmentActivity`

```
@Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) 
    {
           View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.home, container, false);      
           listView = (ListView) view.findViewById(R.id.listView);
           listView.setAdapter(new CustomArrayAdapterForHome(mContext,questions));

           return view;
    }
```

Here is the Adapter for ListView

```
@SuppressLint("DefaultLocale")
    public class CustomArrayAdapterForHome extends EndlessAdapter
    {
        private final LayoutInflater inflator;
        protected ImageLoader imageLoader;
        private DisplayImageOptions options;

        private RotateAnimation rotate=null;
        private View pendingView = null;

        public CustomArrayAdapterForHome(Context ctx,ArrayList<Question> questionList) 
        {
            super( new ArrayAdapter<Question>(ctx, R.layout.question_adapter_layout, questionList));

            inflator = mContext.getLayoutInflater();
            imageLoader = ImageLoader.getInstance();

            options = new DisplayImageOptions.Builder()
                .cacheInMemory()
                .cacheOnDisc()
                .showImageForEmptyUri(R.drawable.user_male)
                .displayer(new RoundedBitmapDisplayer(5))
                .build();

            rotate=new RotateAnimation(0f, 360f, Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF,
                    0.5f, Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF,
                    0.5f);
            rotate.setDuration(600);
            rotate.setRepeatMode(Animation.RESTART);
            rotate.setRepeatCount(Animation.INFINITE);
        }

        class ViewHolder 
        {
            // MY CODE
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return questions.size();
        }

        @Override
        public long getItemId(int position) {
            return position;
        }

        @Override
        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) 
        {       
            final Question question = questions.get(position);
            final OpenionUser myUser = question.getUser();
            // MY CODE


            return view;
        }



          @Override
          protected View getPendingView(ViewGroup parent) 
          {
            View row = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.row, null);

            pendingView = row.findViewById(android.R.id.text1);
            pendingView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            pendingView=row.findViewById(R.id.throbber);
            pendingView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            startProgressAnimation();

            return(row);
          }


        private void startProgressAnimation() 
        {
            if (pendingView!=null) 
            {
                  pendingView.startAnimation(rotate);
            }
        }

        @Override
        protected void appendCachedData() 
        {

        }

        @Override
        protected boolean cacheInBackground() throws Exception 
        {
            getQuestions();
            return true;
        }
    }
```

The above code is just behaving like simple ListView, cacheInBackground Or getPendingView are not getting called. FurtherMore I want to add a headerView too and its not working either.

What am I missing in this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most of the code that you have here does not belong in an `EndlessAdapter`. Quoting [the documentation](https://github.com/commonsguy/cwac-endless):

> It is designed to wrap around another adapter, where you have your "real" data. Hence, it follows the Decorator pattern, augmenting your current adapter with new Endless Technology(TM).

So, first, create a **regular `ArrayAdapter`**, and get all the styling and stuff that you want (e.g., your `getView()` implementation). Then, create an `EndlessAdapter` subclass that adds in the "endlessness".

Of note:

- An `EndlessAdapter` subclass should not override `getView()`, as that is where the endless behavior is added
- An `EndlessAdapter` subclass should not override `getCount()`, as that is managed by the `EndlessAdapter` implementation itself

You may wish to examine [the sample app](https://github.com/commonsguy/cwac-endless/tree/master/demo) to see how it implements `EndlessAdapter` subclasses.

Or, since `EndlessAdapter` [will not work with header views](https://github.com/commonsguy/cwac-endless#limitations), you may simply need to switch to a different endless list solution or roll your own.

Comment: Ok I have made to work thanks for above advices. Kindly one small problem. I am doing getQuestions() in cacheInBackground. and adapter.setRunInBackground(false); In my getQuestion() async task after i get modified array readyListener.onItemsReady(questions); works fine. But if I don't get anything i-e my array is not modified,  cacheInBackground repeats infinitely. what to do?

Comment: @MuhammadUmar: You should be returning `false` from `cacheInBackground()` when you have reached the end of your data.